# CFD Broker that only charges for earnings

Tags: fees, broker, cfd

I've created a small piece of software that allows me to invest into CFDs and gain some small profits. However, most brokers I've found require high opening/closing fees that are in most cases a way larger than my earnings (It does rely on small movements and only holds it for a few minutes). Is anyone of you in aware of a broker that has very small opening / closing fees or, even better, that only charges for my profits?

Answer (score 1):

*that only charges for my profits* - do you understand how CFDs work?
For the sake of simplicity, there are four aspects to CFD trading:

(1) bid/offer spread - differs on whether you're doing OTC contract, or have DMA access

(2) margin requirements - usually tiered and each tier has % of required margin

(3) overnight funding

(4) commissions - there are CFDs with no commissions (e.g. cash indices, futures); and there are CFDs where commissions are calculated as % (e.g. equity CFDs).

So, to dissect your question:

*invest into CFDs* - CFD is a contract, you need to be specific - what is the underlying asset?

*high opening/closing fees* - depends on asset class, see above

*only holds it for a few minutes* - you're trying to scalp the market. Some brokers may not like that.

*only charges for my profits* - no, that's not how CFD operate.